# Does π values vary in Hansch-Fujita equations for a given substituent?

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, solubility, physical-organic-chemistry

I was reading about Hansch-Fujita equations from [Hansch-Fujita paramaters](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01077a028) and observed that the $π$ values of substituents (analogous to Hammet $σ$ values) change according to the specific environment as depicted in the following table: [image: p]

I can't understand why is that the case. I mean in Hammet equations the value of $σ$ for a substituent doesn't vary when changing the environment and what varies is the $ρ$ which is a constant specific for each reaction according to [Hammet Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammett_equation). That is in Hammet equation we have:

$$\log{\frac{K_i}{K}}=ρ\cdotσ$$

But Hansch-Fujita define $π$ (the analogous of $σ$) as:

$$π=\log{K_Χ}-\log{K_Η}$$

So does they have "include" the $ρ$ constant in the value of $π$?